# How to make a query linq check date is in month, quarter or a year

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a User table with `userdateregistered` field, and want to show User registered in the current month, last month, current quarter, last quarte, current year and last year (date reference is datetime.now).I need to build a linq query

For example:

2013/12/31  if is in the month December(12)

2012/01/15 if is in the first quarter (1)

2013/05/12 if is in the year 2012.

Comment: You haven't provide enough information about your problem. So, answer will be - use methods `IsInMonth`, `IsInQuarter`, `IsInYear`

Answer (score 0):

Here is query which select all users from current month

```
DateTime startOfMonth = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1 - DateTime.Today.Day);
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

var users =
   from u in context.Users
   where EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(u.UserDateRegistered) >= startOfMonth &&
         EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(u.UserDateRegistered) <= today
   select u;
```

It shows you idea of filtering by date. Just calculate appropriate begin and end dates. And use [EntityFunctions.TruncateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx) method to compare only dates.

---

Actually I'd created class `DateRange` for holding begin and end dates, and creating some ranges:

```
public class DateRange
{
    public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public static DateRange OfYear(int year)
    {
        return new DateRange
        {
            BeginDate = new DateTime(year, 1, 1),
            EndDate = new DateTime(year, 12, 31)
        };
    }

    public static DateRange OfMonth(int month)
    {
        var year = DateTime.Today.Year;

        return new DateRange
        {
            BeginDate = new DateTime(year, month, 1),
            EndDate = new DateTime(year, month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
        };
    }
}
```

It will allow you to create filter ranges easily:

```
var range = DateRange.OfMonth(10);
var users =
   from u in context.Users
   where EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(u.UserDateRegistered) >= range.BeginDate &&
         EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(u.UserDateRegistered) <= range.EndDate
   select u;
```

Comment: And how could I also filter by current quarter and last quarter? Thanks it is a great idea!!!!

Comment: @user2112420 I think you should try to accomplish at least part of task by yourself. You have more than enough information to do that. Create another factory method in DateRange class, something like `OfCurrentQuarter` which calculates begin and end date of current quarter.