# How to show data for Year to Date by using LINQ in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to show the total **Sales** record for **YearToDate** for a selected Month of the Selected Year for a Shop.Suppose a User selects Year = 2012 and Month = July, so the total of **YearToDate** for the Shop would be the sum of all record from January of 2012 till July of 2012. How can this be done using LINQ?

My approach:

```
ShowRecordForYearToDate(year, monthFrom, MonthTo)
{
    ...
}
```

Question is to calculate **YearToDate** total I have to set MonthFrom = First month of the selected Year, how that can be done in LINQ? Sales record have a property **SalesDate** as `datetime`.

I had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15101301/1108500), but not sure if this how I should approach.

Excuse me if this question is too trivial, but to a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var YTDTotal = Sales.Where(s => s.Date.Year = year 
                             && s.Date.Month >= monthFrom
                             && s.Date.Month <= monthTo
                          )
                    .Sum(s=>s.Amount);
```

or if it's always from January just

```
var YTDTotal = Sales.Where(s => s.Date.Year = year 
                             && s.Date.Month <= monthTo
                          )
                    .Sum(s=>s.Amount);
```

Comment: @D Stanley: The Date.Month was the confusing part. Thanks for clearing the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Shop.Where(s => s.Year == year && a.month      >= monthFrom && s.month <= monthTo).Sum(s     => s.Sales)
```